# Clear all events Google calendar Java

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I need to delete all my calendar events.

I saw the API that's the way to delete all events:

```
// Clear a calendar
service.calendars().clear('primary').execute();
```

So, I do this in my code :

```
 service.calendars().clear(CALENDAR_ID).execute();
```

I have the necessary authorization but I'm having this error :

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Cannot clear primary calendar.",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Cannot clear primary calendar."
}.
```

How do I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

[Calendars: clear](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/clear)

> Clears a primary calendar. This operation deletes all events
>   associated with the primary calendar of an account.

It only works on the primary calendar you need to do

```
service.calendars().clear('primary').execute();
```

not use a calendar id.

Comment: But if I want to delete the events in this specific calendar?

Comment: Get a list of events in that calendar and delete them one at a time

Comment: I have not been able to get that command to work on anything but primary

Comment: i tried calendarList.clear(), but not work! It has some way by the time I created the calendar I can make it primary?

Comment: For secondary calendar, you can either call calendars.delete() or have a for loop deleting all the events if you need to preserve the calendar id for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem. Try to delete all evens from a calendar because some of them are bugged and it's impossible to delete them one by one. For example :

1 :

```
kind    "calendar#event"
etag    "\"3137773029614000\""
id  "3s3rabieiic4602kq267cu5t6n"
status  "cancelled"
```

2 :

```
kind    "calendar#event"
etag    "\"3137773029614000\""
id  "3s3rabieiic4602kq267cu5t6n_20180627T080000Z"
status  "cancelled"
recurringEventId    "3s3rabieiic4602kq267cu5t6n_R20180627T080000"
originalStartTime   
dateTime    "2018-06-27T10:00:00+02:00"
timeZone    "Europe/Paris"
```

AS you can see, they are approximately the same ID. I have 6 more like that.